# Upon removal of text-boxes, how to renumber the rest of the text-boxes' names attribute?

Tags: jquery, html, paypal

The code pasted beneath technically works in the sense that the jquery code that I wrote works when clicked upon. (not js/jquery person)

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t2t1mxqd/

However, the issue is that this is paypal stuff, and if you notice each input (both hidden and not hidden) are numbered.

```
    <div class="removal">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Program 1">Program 1
        <input class="removal" type="text" name="amount_1" value="10.00">
        <button type="button">Remove</button> 
    </div>
```

Like take the first one for example: it has `item_name_1` in the hidden one, and the `amount_1` in the not hidden line.

It's not an issue if it's removed from the bottoms-up, ie, the numbers stay numbered sequentially from top-down.

It is an issue if they're removed randomly or from top-down.

Then the numbers obviously don't start from `item_name_1`, etc.

How do I rewrite the code that when a person chooses to say, remove Program 5, that the rest of the attributes of both `item_name_n` and `name_n` gets rewritten sequentially, or still functions?

Any advice?

Thank you.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $(".removal").click(function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
}); 
</script> 

<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
        method="post">

    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="kin@kinskards.com">

    <!-- Specify an Add to Cart button. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">

    <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name"
        value="Donations to Programs">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">

    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">

    <div class="removal">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Program 1">Program 1
        <input class="removal" type="text" name="amount_1" value="10.00">
        <button type="button">Remove</button> 
    </div>

    <br /><br />

    <div class="removal">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Program 2">Program 2
        <input  type="text" name="amount_2" value="10.00">
             <button type="button">Remove</button> 
    </div>
    <br /><br />

    <div class="removal">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_3" value="Program 3">Program 3
        <input type="text" name="amount_3" value="10.00">
        <button type="button">Remove</button> 
    </div>

    <br /><br />

    <div class="removal">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_4" value="Program 4">Program 4
        <input type="text" name="amount_4" value="10.00">
        <button type="button">Remove</button>
    </div>

    <br /><br />

    <div class="removal">
        <input  type="hidden" name="item_name_5" value="Program 5">Program 5
        <input  type="text" name="amount_5" value="10.00">
        <button type="button">Remove</button> 
    </div>

    <br /><br />

    <div class="removal">
           <input  type="hidden" name="item_name_6" value="Program 6">Program 6
        <input  type="text" name="amount_6" value="10.00">
        <button type="button">Remove</button>  
    </div>

    <br /><br />

    <div class="removal">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_7" value="Program 7">Program 7
        <input  type="text" name="amount_7" value="10.00">
        <button type="button">Remove</button> 
    </div>

        <br /><br />

    <div class="removal">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_8" value="Program 8">Program 8
        <input  type="text" name="amount_8" value="10.00">
        <button type="button">Remove</button> 
    </div>
        <br /><br />

    <div class="removal">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_9" value="Program 9">Program 9
        <input type="text" name="amount_9" value="10.00">
        <button type="button">Remove</button> 
    </div>

    <br /><br />

    <div class="removal">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_10" value="Program 10">Program 10
        <input type="text" name="amount_10" value="10.00">
        <button type="button">Remove</button> 
    </div>

    <br /><br />

    <div class="removal">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_11" value="Program 11">Program 11
        <input  type="text" name="amount_11" value="10.00">
         <button type="button">Remove</button> 
    </div>


    <br /><br />

    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
    <input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
        src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif"
        alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
    <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"
        src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
</form>


<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
        method="post">

<!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="kin@kinskards.com">

<!-- Specify a PayPal Shopping Cart View Cart button. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="display" value="1">


<br /><br />
<!-- Display the View Cart button. -->
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
        src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_viewcart_LG.gif"
       alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"
        src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
</form>
```

Comment: What's your backend language?  If you are using PHP then you don't need to increment the names, you can just name them all `business[]` or `cmd[]` and PHP loads them into properly ordered arrays to be accessed by index on the backend.  ie, `$_POST['cmd'][0]` would line up with it's counterpart `$_POST['display'][0]` and so on and so forth.

Comment: @AndrewCoder, um. No backend language here. It's literally as you see it here ... was just hoping to use jQuery to resolve the dilemma as mentioned in the question ... if I misunderstood your question, let me know.

Comment: Oh I see, you are POSTing straight to paypal server.  You could probably try it as in my first comment and see how paypal handles it with a test.  It may work just fine.  I would hope paypal is smart enough to handle array forms like that. (and no you didn't misinterpret my question, I missed the paypal portion of this)

Comment: @AndrewCoder, hm ... I would if I knew PHP ... which I don't. Plus .. paypal in my rather limited experience tends to be rather fussy ... so ... not sure if what you suggested would work because honestly, it took me forever to even get this working. And the only reason why this form is laid out like this is because someone at work wants to allow people to be able to customize their donation amount per program. I want to allow the option of removing programs if people aren't interested in it.

Comment: No worries, I'd try it without the integers (field `name="name[]"`) and push one or two through to paypal and just see if the cart looks right.  Pretty sure you still get a confirmation to press before it would actually process the transaction.

Comment: @AndrewCoder, you mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4ddydv8n/ it didn't for me ...

Comment: Ah yea paypal doesn't like it without the numbers.  And if you remove an inside number (remove #2 for instance leaving 1 and 3) the cart only sees the first item.  It looks like an answer was posted that will work, re-number all the fields after a removal.

Comment: @AndrewCoder, yep, the answer works! Thank you for taking the time to respond, and clarifying my question further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will keep the `input` names sequential, without affecting anything else, which I assume is your goal:

```
$('.removal button').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();

  $('.removal [type="hidden"]').each(function(idx) {
    $(this).attr('name', 'item_name_'+(idx+1));
  });

  $('.removal [type="text"]').each(function(idx) {
    $(this).attr('name', 'amount_'+(idx+1));
  });
});
```

You can also clean up your code a bit by removing this code:

```
<br /><br />
```

… and adding a bottom margin to the `removal` class:

```
.removal {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

That way, you won't end up with blank spaces when you remove rows.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8tzvnfhw/1/)

Comment: @RickHitchcock, this works! Thank you! I was testing your answer out on the site and it wasn't working till I remembered that I had to enclose your jquery in document.ready which I forgot. Anyway, thank you for nailing the precise purpose of what I had asked for. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Somthing along te lines of this, but not tested. Concept is usable.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".removal").click(function() {
        $(this).remove();

         for(var i =0;i<$(".remove").length;i++)
    {
        var $inputs = $(this).children("input");

        $inputs.each(function(){

            var thisType = $(this).attr("type");

            switch(thisType){

                case "text":

                    $(this).attr("name", "name_" + i);
                    $(this).val(i + ".00");
                    break;
                case "hidden":
                     $(this).attr("name", "item_name_" + i);
                    $(this).val("Program " + i);
                    break;
            }            
        });

    }
    });
```

});

Comment: I would use this concept, maybe clean up in some ways. Basically, once you remove a .remove item, then get all remaining items with that class, and reset the attributes "name" and "value" accordingly in a loop. This will give yo the effect you are wanting. I will try this in fiddle, and tweak it if something an issue.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to respond to my question. Appreciate it. Happy Friday!

Comment: No problem. Is this the answer you were looking for? If so, can you mark it. I tried it though, and not functioing, so I will update the code to a working copy paste snippet.